# How to access the data member of one function into another function inside same class in c++

Tags: c++

I wanted to declare the array of string to the limit provided by user. So I take limit in getData(), and declare the string inside getData function. As a whole I want to take students name  and display it in the same class. Sorry for basic question and thank you in advance.

```
class student
{
    int limit;
public:
    void getData()
    {
        cout<<"Enter the number of students: ";
        cin>>limit;
        string name[limit];
        cout<<"Enter the names of students: \n";
        for(int i=0; i<limit; i++)
          cin>>name[i];
    }
   void showData()
    {
        cout<<"The list of students: \n";
        for(int i=0; i<limit; i++)
            cout<<name[i]<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    student s1;
    s1.getData();
    s1.showData();
    return 0;
}
```

Here in this function, error comes as "name was not declared in this scope". sorry in advance if it is nonsense.

```
void showData()
        {
            cout<<"The list of students: \n";
            for(int i=0; i<limit; i++)
                cout<<name[i]<<endl;
        }
```

Comment: Fyi, `string name[limit];` is a terrible idea. Variable length arrays (VLAs) aren't standard C++, and you're playing with fire by using non-POD types in one even if your platform does "support" them. As far as your problem is concerned, the plurality paradox of `class student` hosting multiple names of multiple *students* (plural) is a strong indicator that you need to rethink this design.

Comment: Well, `name` is a local variable, so it is not present in `showData`, you can make it a member, just like `limit`. You should really be using `std::vector` for that though.

Comment: @WhozCraig He could as well rename the class from `Student` to `Students` ;) The design problem is, that the class does too much (IO and storage) or that the class itself is not necessary, where a `std::vector<std::string>` and 2 functions would do.

Comment: @BitTickler That would be the "rethink this design" I eluded to. I concur, btw.

Comment: You would probably benefit from taking the time to carefully write out your requirements. Your question currently looks to me like you aimed for brevity at the expense of clarity. Don't do that. Learn to write precise functional specs before working on conciseness. *When you re-write your specs, be sure to provide justifications for your current design decisions, especially why `name` is local to a member function and `limit` is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your code is that `string name` is defined in `getData()` but not in `showData()`. What I would do is declare a member variable `vector<string> name` like you did with `int limit`. I would use a vector instead of an array because it's easier to code for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class student
{
    int limit;
    vector<string> name;
public:
    void getData()
    {
        cout<<"Enter the number of students: ";
        cin>>limit;
        cout<<"Enter the names of students: \n";
        for(int i=0; i<limit; i++)
        {
            string temp;
            cin>>temp;
            name.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
   void showData()
    {
        cout<<"The list of students: \n";
        for(int i=0; i<limit; i++)
            cout<<name[i]<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    student s1;
    s1.getData();
    s1.showData();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of students: 3
Enter the names of students: 
andy
max
rose
The list of students: 
andy
max
rose
```

Comment: Not a critique per-se, but always good to mention it is good to provide the user with a meaningful prompt for each student to help guide the user-input. Simple addition of `std::cout << "  student[" << i <<"]: ";` before reading the student name is fine (your `temp`).